# Inspectdb in Oracle-Django gets OCI-22061: invalid format text [T

Tags: django, django-models, oracle-xe, cx-oracle, inspectdb

I'm using `Oracle Database 10g xe universal Rel.10.2.0.1.0 against cx_Oracle-5.0.4-10g-unicode-py26-1.x86_64 on a django project on Ubuntu 10.04`

My db is generated by `Oracle 10gr2 enterprise edition` (on Windows XP, import done in `US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set`, import server uses `AL32UTF8 character set`, export client uses `EL8MSWIN1253 character set`)

When I try `django-admin.py inspectdb` I get the following error:

> ......."indexes = connection.introspection.get_indexes(cursor,
>   table_name)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/oracle/introspection.py",
>   line 116, in get_indexes
>       for row in cursor.fetchall():   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line
>   483, in fetchall
>       for r in self.cursor.fetchall()]) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: OCI-22061: invalid format text [T".

I am aware of `"inspectdb works with PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite"` but as I understand from other posts it also works with Oracle somehow.

Does anyone know why I get this error or how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try it with updating cx_Oracle 5.1.1 package, then try this:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download cx_Oracle-5.1.2 and fix the issue using below command.

**$ wget -c http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/cx-oracle/cx_Oracle-5.1.2-11g-py27-1.x86_64.rpm**

Command to install rpm

**$ sudo yum install cx_Oracle-5.0.4-11g-unicode-py27-1.x86_64.rpm**

Also download Oracle instantclient **http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/11101/basic-11.1.0.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip** and **http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/11101/sdk-11.1.0.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip**

Extract the above downloaded zip file.
copy the **include** folder from **sdk-11.1.0.6.0-linux-x86_64** and paste in **basic-11.1.0.6.0-linux-x86_64**
Set the below path in **.bashrc** file

***export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/oracle_lib/oracle_instantclient_11_1***

***export $ORACLE_HOME = /oracle_lib/oracle_instantclient_11_1***

*$ **ls /oracle_lib/oracle_instantclient_11_1***

You should find the *include* folder with list of files

Then execute .bashrc file using $ **source ~/.bashrc**

I have tested it.